# Making particles move around the object smoother

Tags: processing, point, particles

i was able to make particles go around the ellipse I created which was my previous question. Now I have another one, flow of the particles are not as smooth as i want, there is this diagonal looking shape they follow and when you move the mouse (the ellipse) you can see my lines of my "force" variable. Again I want particles to move like water floating around a rock in a river.

[Link for the previous question I asked about same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511697/processing-particle)

```java
int NUM_PARTICLES = 9000;
ParticleSystem p;
Rock r;
void setup()
{
  smooth();
  size(700,700,P2D);
  p = new ParticleSystem();
  r = new Rock();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  p.update();
  p.render();
  r.rock();

}

float speed = 2;
float rad = 100;
class Particle
{
  PVector position, velocity;
  float initialPosY;

  Particle()
  {
    position = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    initialPosY = position.y;
    velocity = new PVector();
  }

  void update()
  {

    velocity.x = speed;
    velocity.y = 0;

    float d = dist (position.x, position.y, mouseX, mouseY);
    if (d < rad) {
      float force = map(d, 0, rad, speed, 0);
      if (position.x < mouseX) {
        if (position.y < mouseY) {
          velocity.y = -force;
        } else {
          velocity.y = force;
        }
      } else {
        if (position.y < mouseY) {
          velocity.y = force;
        } else {
          velocity.y = -force;
        }
      }
      position.add(velocity);
    } else {
      position = new PVector(position.x+speed, initialPosY);
    }



    if (position.x<0)position.x+=width;
    if (position.x>width)position.x-=width;
    if (position.y<0)position.y+=height;
    if (position.y>height)position.y-=height;
  }

  void render()
  {
    stroke(255, 255, 255, 80);
    point(position.x, position.y);
  }
}

class ParticleSystem
{
  Particle[] particles;

  ParticleSystem()
  {
    particles = new Particle[NUM_PARTICLES];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++)
    {
      particles[i]= new Particle();
    }
  }

  void update()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++)
    {
      particles[i].update();
    }
  }

  void render()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++)
    {
      particles[i].render();
    }
  }
}

class Rock{

  void rock()
  {
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(4);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,50,50);

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be a lot easier if you try to narrow your problem down to a smaller [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like I did in the answer to your first question:

```java
PVector position;
PVector speed;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  position = new PVector(250, 0);
  speed = new PVector(0, 1);
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if (dist(position.x, position.y, mouseX, mouseY) < 100) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    if (position.x < mouseX) {
      position.x--;
    } else {
      position.x++;
    }
  } else {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  ellipse(position.x, position.y, 20, 20);

  position.add(speed);

  if (position.y > height) {
    position.y = 0;
  }

  if (position.x < 0) {
    position.x = width;
  } else if (position.x > width) {
    position.x = 0;
  }
}
```

Now that we have that, we can talk about how we might improve it.

Right now, our logic for having the particles avoid our obstacle is here:

```java
if (dist(position.x, position.y, mouseX, mouseY) < 100) {
    if (position.x < mouseX) {
      position.x--;
    } else {
      position.x++;
    }
}
```

Notice that we're always moving the particle by 1 pixel, which is why it looks blocky. What we need to do is smooth our transition out by moving the pixel only a little bit at first, and then moving it more as it gets closer to the obstacle.

You might user the [`lerp()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) or [`map()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/map_.html) function for this, but for this simple example, we can simply use the `dist()` function.

Here is a super simple approach you might take:

```java
float distance = dist(position.x, position.y, mouseX, mouseY);

if (position.x < mouseX) {
  position.x -= 1000/(distance*distance);
} else {
  position.x += 1000/(distance*distance);
}
```

Notice that by squaring the distance, I'm setting up a [polynomical interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). In other words, the particle moves faster the closer it gets to the center of the boundary.

Again, you're going to have to play with this to get the exact effect you're looking for, but the basic idea is there: what you're looking for is an interpolation (how fast the particle moves) that scales with the distance from the boundary. You can use squaring to exaggerate the effect.

You could also use basic trig to make the particle follow a circular path.